# Where to know/check: Int32 inherits from ValueType, ValueType inherits from Object?

Tags: .net, object, value-type, int32

I cannot find the relationships between these types using .Net reflector. Any idea?

Comment: Nice question, i'm interesting too but i think you cannot see it in reflector cause only keywords like scruct or enum defines type as value for compiler.

Comment: @Denis you can see it in the IL, the C# and the tree...

Comment: the object browser in VS should also give you the same information...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you say "using .Net reflector":

[image]

If you wanted reflection:

```
Type type = typeof (int);
while(type != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);
    type = type.BaseType;
}
```

which shows:

```
System.Int32
System.ValueType
System.Object
```

and if you mean the IL:

```
.class public sequential ansi serializable sealed beforefieldinit Int32
    extends System.ValueType
```

and:

```
.class public abstract auto ansi serializable beforefieldinit ValueType
    extends System.Object
```

(in reflector, select the type's node, and select IL as the view)

If you mean the C# view, then:

```
public struct Int32 ...
```

is enough; the `struct` keyword **means**: inherits from `ValueType` (although not quite in the usual C# `class` way). `ValueType` remains a regular class, and has:

```
public abstract class ValueType ...
```

and as usual, a `class` which doesn't specify a base-type means: inherits from `object`.

Comment: I mean the C# view. Everyting is clear now. Thanks Marc for giving different approaches which is great.